# How to avoid using nested aggregate functions?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I need some help here, I'm sure you guys know how to do it:
Let's start with table structure:

```
author(name, nationality, Gender);
article(title, year, conference);
publication(articleTitle, authorName);
```

I need to know the Gender of authors which have the highest number of publications. By the Way I'm using PostgreSQL, don't know if that matters.

Here's My idea:

```
select gender from author
join publication on(name = authorName)
having (count(articleTitle) = max(count(articleTitle)))
group by gender
```

Now, I know i cannot use nested aggregate functions, and that's why I'm trying to use nested selects, something like `select gender where gender in (another select)` But I did not managed to avoid the aggregate function issue.
Hope you can help me, Thank you

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query gets you the authors, ordered by the number of publications:

```
select a.name, a.gender, count(*) as num_publications
from author a join
     publication p
     on a.name = p.authorName
group by a.name, a.gender
order by num_publications desc;
```

If you want the top three, then use `fetch first` or `limit`:

```
select a.name, a.gender, count(*) as num_publications
from author a join
     publication p
     on a.name = p.authorName
group by a.name, a.gender
order by num_publications desc
fetch first 3 rows only;
```